# Prevent new-line in Bootstrap4-apha6 breadcrumb

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, bootstrap-4, twitter-bootstrap-4

When the text in the breadcrumbs in Bootstrap4-aplha6 is too long the las crumb will jump to the next line:

```html
<nav class="breadcrumb">
  <a class="breadcrumb-item" href="#">Home</a>
  <a class="breadcrumb-item" href="#">Library</a>
  <a class="breadcrumb-item" href="#">Data</a>
  <span class="breadcrumb-item active">A slightly too long title</span>
</nav>
```

Produces:

```
 ---------------------------------
|                                 |
| Home / Library / Data           |
|   / A slightly too long title   |
|                                 |
|                                 |
|                                 |
 \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\
```

And I would like:

```
 ---------------------------------
|                                 |
| Home / Library / Data / A slig… |
|                                 |
|                                 |
|                                 |
 \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\
```

I have tried fixing this with `white-space: nowrap`, `overflow: hidden` and `text-overflow: ellipsis` and it does not seem to work well because, for some reason, in Bootstrap4, the breadcrumb-items are blocks floated left.

Did anyone find the way to fix this without overwriting all the Bootstrap classes (the ellipsis is not 100% necessary)?

Comment: what about setting width of floated blocks and then overflow: hidden?

Comment: There is no way I can know beforehand the with of each `breadcrumb-item`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Michael's solution seems no longer work with Bootstrap 4.1 when using the official breadcrumb snippet (with `<ol>` and `<li>` tags). Here is another solution.

```css
.breadcrumb {
    display: block !important;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.breadcrumb .breadcrumb-item {
    display: inline;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

    <div class="container">             
        <nav aria-label="breadcrumb">
            <ol class="breadcrumb">
                <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="#">My category</a></li>
                <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="#">My category</a></li>
                <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="#">My category</a></li>
                <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="#">My category</a></li>
                <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="#">My category</a></li>
                <li class="breadcrumb-item active" aria-current="page">My page</li>       
            </ol>
        </nav>        
    </div>
```

Answer (score 4):

Don't float `.breadcrumb-item`. Set both `.breadcrumb` and `.breadcrumb-item` to `white-space: nowrap;`. Then add `overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis;` to `.breadcrumb` to create the ellipsis.

```css
.breadcrumb, .breadcrumb-item {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.breadcrumb .breadcrumb-item {
  float: none;
}
.breadcrumb {
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<nav class="breadcrumb">
  <a class="breadcrumb-item" href="#">Home</a>
  <a class="breadcrumb-item" href="#">asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf a asdf asdf asdf asdf sadf</a>
  <a class="breadcrumb-item" href="#">Data</a>
  <span class="breadcrumb-item active">A slightly llllllitle</span>
</nav>
```

Comment: Great! I was just going to comment about the overflow and you edited the answer! That should become a Bootstrap feature! ;)

Comment: Seems not working with Bootstrap 4.1 and the official breadcrumb example (with <ol> and <li> items).

Answer (score 3):

**Bootstrap 4.1.3**

Apply `.flex-nowrap` to the `.breadcrumb` element, and then `.text-truncate` to `.breadcrumb-item` elements you wish to clip.  This has the effect of forcing the breadcrumb container to not wrap, and then each element must fit within it, truncating text.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container m-5" style="width:450px">
  <nav class="breadcrumb flex-nowrap">
    <a class="breadcrumb-item">Home</a>
    <a class="breadcrumb-item text-truncate">Library</a>
    <a class="breadcrumb-item text-truncate">Data</a>
    <a class="breadcrumb-item text-truncate">Thursday</a>
    <span class="breadcrumb-item active text-truncate">A slightly too long title</span>
  </nav>
</div>
```